# Facebook Page Video Upload API Permission Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a video to a facebook page via the FB Page API

`POST` Request to `https://graph-video.facebook.com/v12.0/<PAGEID>/videos` where `<PAGEID>` is the page id.

POST PARAMS:

- `access_token` (This is the page access token acquired by the `Page List` API
- `file_url` (public accessible file)

However, I get an error response of:

```
error: {
    code: 100
    fbtrace_id: "A1J_75XwMn_p_KSjtZYGeGL"
    message: "(#100) No permission to publish the video"
    type: "OAuthException"
}
```

I even used the Graph Explorer tool to generate the access token.

My user is an Admin of said page and also has the following scopes:

`email, user_link, pages_show_list, user_photos, publish_actions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_actions` is deprecated, there are new permissions for posting to a Page now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/overview/permissions-features

> The pages_manage_posts permission allows your app to create, edit and delete your Page posts

Although, the /videos endpoint seems to be gone: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/page/videos